# 2006 auto dipstick missing on my vectra C

Tags: automatic-transmission

I cannot find a gearbox dipstick at on my 2006 Vectra C 150 cdTI.
No dipstick can be seen at all.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Where have you looked?

Comment: Does the owner's manual say anything about it?

Answer (score 2):

Some cars don't have a dip stick.  There will be a procedure where you add fluid through a filler hole in the side of the sump until fluid starts to come out of the filler hole.  You usually have to do this with the engine running while someone goes through the gears.  Obviously you need to ensure the car cannot move while doing this.

Comment: Where do you add the fluid ?

Comment: In the filler hole on the side of the sump.

Comment: Your transmission may be like this one on YouTube - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ipdcU24uXxU

Comment: This document does make it look like there may be a dipstick though - https://www.vectra-c.com/forum/uploader/pics/pics1/AF23_AF33%20transmission%20fluid%20change.pdf